# Inserting python variables into Sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, python-3.10

I am sorting out an error for my database so I have tried to isolate the problem. This function is the problem but more specifically the `c.execute("INSERT INTO details VALUES(?, ?)",(e ,cp ,))`.
This causes this error:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO details VALUES(?, ?)",(e ,cp ,))
```

sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

I'll put the rest of the function underneath:

```
import sqlite3
def echecker():
    email = False
    password = False
    right = 0
    e = "the@test.com"
    p = "test"
    cp = "test"
    space = 0
        
    conn = sqlite3.connect("U+P.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""SELECT email FROM details""")
    data = c.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    index = 0
    for row in data:
        if row[index] == e:
           right = right + 1
        else:
           print("right")
    print()
    e = list(e)
    print(e)
    while space < len(e) and right == 0 and email == False:
        if e[0] == "@" and e[space] == "@":
           space = space + 1
           print("wrong")
        elif e[space] == "@":
             email = True
             print("right")
        else:
             space = space + 1
             print("wrong")
    print()
    if p == cp:
        password = True
        print("right")
    print()
    if password == True and email == True and right == 0:
       conn = sqlite3.connect("U+P.db")
       print("a")
       c = conn.cursor()
       print("a")
       c.execute("INSERT INTO details VALUES(?, ?)",(e ,cp ,))
       print("a")
       conn.commit()
       print("siuu")
echecker()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you reassign `e` to a list `e = list(e)`. Of course the subsequent attempt to supply `e` as a query parameter will fail.